# Clearing Data from a Data Extension through API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am trying to clear a data extension via API call. I have ExactTarget web service reference into my project as https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

I have found a sample code to clear a data extension via API call at here on ET website:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/clearing_data_from_a_data_extension/

I have tried using the sample code provided on ET website, but I am getting an error resolving this reference:

**ExactTarget.Integration.IPartnerFrameworkInterface proxy = null;**

Can someone please explain how to resolve this reference? My full code can be seen in this image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the examples are using the references defined in [the API Starter Kit](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/api_starter_kits/).

---

Alternatively, check the name you gave the Service or Web Reference. It will need to be "ExactTarget" to match the given example. E.g.

[image]

Note that in the screenshot above I added the reference to https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl rather than the development environment https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx. When I tried [the development environment web services](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/) I got a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

Comment: I cannot find any example in the API Starter Kit which references to the the namespace 'Integration' or 'Integration.IPartnerFrameworkInterface'.

I have followed the exact steps mentioned here and added reference to https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl but still cannot resolve the reference and getting this error:

'Type of namespace name ‘Integration’ does not exist in the namespace ‘ExactTarget’ (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

It seems like the API doesn't have the namespace ‘Integration’